# How to merge two array into one object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hello i have JSON response with structure like below, you can see "postID" and "judul" is inside one object with the parent is numeric array

```
[
    {
        "postID": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ],
        "judul": [
            "Tes",
            "a",
            "TesFront"
        ]
    },
    {
        "postID": [
            4,
            5
        ],
        "judul": [
            "Testing",
            ""
        ]
    },
]
```

What i want to do is simply just to make "postID" and "judul" into one new object with key named "newKey" with the value inside is an object with "postID" key and "judul" key you can see the different from previouse is now "postID" and "judul" is inside "newKey" object, like this:

```
[
    {
        "newKey": {
          "postID": [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],        
          "judul": [
            "Tes",
            "a",
            "TesFront"
          ]
        },
    },
    {
        "newKey":{
        "postID": [
            4,
            5
        ],
        "judul": [
            "Testing",
            ""
        ]
}
    },
]
```

Hope someone can help me to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I want to merge "postID" and "judul" into one new object key

Comment: I don't see a difference between jsons you posted

Comment: Answer from David already solve this question @Serge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the problem being presented.  You effectively want to turn an array of this object:

```
{
  "prop1": "val",
  "prop2": "val2"
}
```

Into an array of this object:

```
{
  "newprop": {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2"
  }
}
```

You can project an array into a new shape with `.map`.  For example:

```
var newArr = arr.map(x => {
  return {
    newprop: {
      prop1: x.prop1,
      prop2: x.prop2
    }
  }
});
```

So yours might look something like this:

```
var newArr = arr.map(x => {
  return {
    namaBagian: x.namaBagian,
    bagianID: x.bagianID,
    newKey: {
      postID: x.postID,
      judul: x.judul
    }
  }
});
```

If the shape of the objects is more dynamic, you could potentially make clever use of the spread operator to not have to specify every value explicitly.  But the general principle is the same.  What you're looking to do is map an array into a new array, where each element takes on a new shape built from the data on the existing element.